# Showing $(0,1)^3$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1)^3$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology

Showing $(0,1)^3$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1)^3$

So, if these spaces are homeomorphic, then if we remove any single point from each of them, they will still be homeomorphic.

$(0,1)^3 - \{p\}\cong S^2$

While

$[0,1)^3 - \{0\} \cong \mathbb{R}^3$

But $H_2(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2(\mathbb{R}^3) \cong 0$.

Thus we have $(0,1)^3 - \{p\} \ncong [0,1)^3 - \{0\}$

$\therefore$ $(0,1)^3$ $\ncong$ $[0,1)^3$

Comment: $[0,1)^3 - \{0\} \cong \mathbb{R}^3$ isn't true. But the second homology is still trivial as the space is retractable.

Comment: It is not true that $[0,1)^3-\{0\}\cong \mathbb{R}^3$. Note that the $[0$ causes the Cartesian product to have many boundary (manifold boundary) points, like $(0;0.1;0.1)$.

Comment: I assume you mean $(0,0,0)$. While it is true that $[0,1)^3- \{(0,0,0)\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are homotopy equivalent, it is just because both are contractible. I don't see any "obvious" homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Isn't $[0,1)^3 - \{0\} = (0,1)^3?$

Edit: nvm

Comment: @ConnorMalin You say they are both retractable. Under that assumption there _is_ an obvious homotopy equivalence: a constant map.

Comment: So the point of this proof is that no matter what point I remove from $(0,1)^3$ it is homotopic to $S^2$, meanwhile I can remove a point from $[0,1)^3$ such that the reuslting space is contractible, thus they are not homotopic. 

Is this right?

Comment: @MathematicalMuchroom Maps are homotopic. Spaces are homotopy equivalent. But yes, that's a good way to solve this problem.

Comment: An interesting analytic approach... However did you mean to have that series converge towards the origin where the sets I described are different?

Comment: @Arthur If you know they are contractible it is obvious, but it isn't as natural as having a copy of $S^2$ in your space that is a deformation retract.

Comment: In $[0,1)^3$  the point $(0,0,0)$  has an open nbhd $U$ such that  $  \partial U $ is homeomorphic to the closed unit ball of $\Bbb R^2$. But $(0,1)^3$ is homeomorpic to $\Bbb R^3.$  Does there exist an open $V$ in $\Bbb R^3  $ such that $\partial V$ is homemorphic to the closed unit ball of $\Bbb R^2$?